# Cannot access ADO.NET Entity Data Model in MVC webAPI solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

My project consist of: MVC, WEB API solution.

I have generated an ADO.NET entity data model from my database schema and it resides in the app_code folder.

I tried to access the ADO.NET entiy data model from the models folder and the controllers folder and i cannot get access to it.

Should I have the ADO.NET entity data model in the App_Code folder?

How do we access the data model from the mvc application?

Typically it is as easy as MydatabaseNameModel db = new MydatabaseNameModel(); However, it is not visible this way.

Do i need to import something in the webAPI so the MydatabaseNameModel becomes implementable?

Comment: Are you `using` the namespace that your `edmx` file is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have a using statement that points to the namespace that the EDMX is using.

or

Add a new empty project, add the model to that project, then reference the project from the MVC site (also, don't forget the namespace)

Comment: Added a new project,added reference to the new project from my MVC / Web API solution and I now have access to the ADO.NET entity model.